# Unsatisfiedlink error in Android using opencv

Tags: android, opencv

The error is unsatisfiedLinkError when I am trying to initialize MAt object.I am initializing it after the opencv loaded sucessfully.But again the error.please suggest your views.    public    class    NextActivity    extends    Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        String TAG="FinalCamera";
        int selectedFilter,selectedKMap;
        SeekBar seekBar;
        Mat imgMat,tmp;

```
    //native function
    //public native int convertNativeGray(long matAddrRgba, long matAddrGray,int selectedFilter,int ksize);





    //loading and connecting to opencv library
         private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
                @Override
                public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                    switch (status) {
                        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                        {
                            System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample");
                            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                        } break;
                        default:
                        {
                            super.onManagerConnected(status);
                        } break;
                    }
                }
            };


        @Override    
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);
         imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        // bitmap  = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("name");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //for spinner
         Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.filter_spinner);
          // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
          ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                  R.array.Filters, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
          // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
          adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          // Apply the adapter to the spinner
          spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

          spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
          //for kmap
          seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

          seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {


               public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {

                            selectedKMap = progresValue;
                            System.out.println("The selected KMap is"+selectedKMap);
                            }
              public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
              public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
             });
}
         @Override
public void onResume()
{
super.onResume();
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallback);
    realProcessing();   
}
public void realProcessing()
    {
        System.out.println("This is real processing");
        bitmap  = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("name");
         bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
           //here in below line there is error
            tmp = new Mat (bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
           // imgMat = new Mat (bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
          // Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, tmp);
           //convertNativeGray(tmp.getNativeObjAddr(), imgMat.getNativeObjAddr(),2,3);


           //Utils.matToBitmap(imgMat, bitmap);
         imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.next, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    //when seekbar an item is selected then this method will be called
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        selectedFilter=pos+1;
          System.out.println("This is selected filter="+selectedFilter);
    }
    @Override
    //when nothing changed this method will be called
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use opencv code, until mLoaderCallback finishes.

"I am initializing it after the opencv loaded sucessfully" - well, no. you don't.

```
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mLoaderCallback);
realProcessing();
```

OpenCVLoader.initAsync <- that is **async**

you will have to move your realProcessing code to a later stage. either here:

```
 public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                switch (status) {
                    case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    {
                        System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample");
                        Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                        // yes, now it's safe !


                    } break;
```

or to onCameraViewStarted(), onCameraFrame().

Comment: when I move the code below System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample")it shows the error that your nativemethod not found error is:=java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.finalcamera.NextActivity.convertNativeGray:(JJII)I

Comment: and what do you mean by async in OpenCVLoader.initAsync

Comment: Got the answer after removing the native function to the place as said by berek and changing my c++ function name